# How to compare array of array elements between each other in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, arrays, if-statement

i am newly learn javascript, now i am having a serios compare in here.
In one nested array how to compare each array first 2 index, elements of first 4 digit are same to other array elemnts or not?

if array elements are same then will display rest of elemnts for both array in one array.

suppose the codes like this:

```
const arr= [[100110, 556781, 'student', 'single' , 20, 'jacci'],
[100210, 667881 , 'employee', 'double' , 25, 'rock'],
[100310, 778981 ,'teacher', 'triple' , 45, 'poul'],
[100220, 667891 , 'employee', 'single' , 30, 'jack'],
[100320, 778991 ,'teacher', 'double' , 40, 'rose'],
[100120, 556791, 'student', 'double' , 35, 'laila']];
```

now i want to compare each array frist 2 index are same, if same then the array will be like:

```
arry = [[100110, 556781,'student', 'single' , 20, 'jacci','student','double' , 35, 'laila'],
[100210, 667881 , 'employee', 'double' , 25, 'rock','employee','single' , 30, 'jack'],
[100310, 778991 ,'teacher', 'triple' , 45, 'poul', 'teacher','double' , 40, 'rose']]
```

how can i get the array like this in javascript.

anyone can help me to do the function for it.

Thanks for your trying in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do something like this

```js
  const arr= [[100110, 556781, 'student', 'single' , 20, 'jacci'],[100210, 667881 , 'employee', 'double' , 25, 'rock'],[100310, 778981 ,'teacher', 'triple' , 45, 'poul'],[100220, 667891 , 'employee', 'single' , 30, 'jack'],[100320, 778991 ,'teacher', 'double' , 40, 'rose'],[100120, 556791, 'student', 'double' , 35, 'laila']];

const group = (data) => {
  const map = {};

  data.forEach(([id, uid, type, ...rest]) => {
    const key = `${String(id).slice(0, -2)}|${String(uid).slice(0, -2)}|${type}`;
    if (!map[key]) {
       map[key] = [id, uid, type];
    }

    map[key].push(...rest);
  });

  return Object.values(map);
};

console.log(group(arr))
```

Comment: Unexpected token ? getting this error

Comment: how to solve it?

Comment: can you help me one more thing, seems if i wants to compare of first index element not full only 3 digit what should i use for that?

Comment: i have update my question sample, can you please help me to get something like that to compare first 4 digit. because my array something like that, later i found it, sorry for the mistakes i have done first. i really thankful for your help.

Comment: Thanks . i got the concept any way...thanks a lot to manage me data as i expected.

Answer (score 0):

You can try it:

```js
const distinceNestedArray = () => {
    const arr= [[1001, 'student', 'single' , 20, 'jacci'],
    [1002, 'employee', 'double' , 25, 'rock'],
    [1003, 'teacher', 'triple' , 45, 'poul'],
    [1002, 'employee', 'single' , 30, 'jack'],
    [1003, 'teacher', 'double' , 40, 'rose'],
    [1001, 'student', 'double' , 35, 'laila']];
    const result = [];

    for(let item of arr){
        if(!result.length){
            result.push(item);
            continue;
        }
        let foundItem = result.some(x=> x === item || (x[0] === item[0] && x[1] === item[1]));
        if(foundItem){
            continue;
        }
        result.push(item);
    }
    console.log('---result', result)
    return result;
}
distinceNestedArray()
```